# How to check two summands give same summation value without evaluating the sum?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

It is easier for me to explain the question with the following toy example.

Suppose I have two summands,

```
Summand1 = n1 + 2 n2;
Summand2 = 2 n1 + n2;
```

Now, it is easy to see that the summands are equal with respect to the following summation.

```
Sum[Summand, {n1, 0, lim}, {n2, 0, lim}]
```

But I can't think of an excellent way to show on Mathematica that the summands are equal. Of course, one trivial way is to do this,

```
SameQ[Summand1, Summand2] || SameQ[Summand1, Summand2 /. {n1 -> n2, n2 -> n1}]
```

Although this won't look good when we check summands having three or more summation variables, maybe, I need a way to tell Mathematica that `n1` and `n2` are dummy variables.

Any suggestions will be very useful.

Comment: Would something like `Equal @@ (Sum[#, {n1, 0, lim}, {n2, 0, lim}] & /@ {Summand1, 
 Summand2})` work for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try permuting the variables and then sorting and taking the first element of the result. For instance:

```
canon[expr_, vars_List] := First @ Sort @ ReplaceAll[
    expr,
    Thread[vars -> Permutations @ vars]
]
```

Then:

```
c1 = canon[n1 + 2 n2, {n1, n2}]
c2 = canon[2 n1 + n2, {n1, n2}]

c1 === c2
```

> 2 n1 + n2

> 2 n1 + n2

> True